# How to count the number of function evaluations in NIntegrate

Tags: numerical-integration

I expect the following code to count the number of function calls in `NIntegrate`.

```
i = 0;
f[x_] := (i += 1; Tanh[x] Sin[Exp[x]] Exp[-0.55 x^2 Exp[x^2]])
Print[NIntegrate[f[x], {x, -2, 1}]] 
Print[i]
```

However, the output is

```
0.0901049
2
```

which means only 2 function calls in NIntegrate. It's hard to believe converged result can be obtained by merely two function calls. What's happening here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the option [`EvaluationMonitor`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/EvaluationMonitor.html)

```
Block[{k = 0}, {NIntegrate[f[x], {x, -2, 1}, EvaluationMonitor :> k++], k}]
```

> {0.0901049, 121}

Without using `EvaluationMonitor` you can do

```
ClearAll[f, ff]
f[x_] := Tanh[x] Sin[Exp[x]] Exp[-0.55 x^2 Exp[x^2]]

i = 0;
ff[y_?NumberQ] := Block[{x = y}, i++; f[x]]

{NIntegrate[ff[x], {x, -2, 1}], i}
```

> {0.0901049, 121}

Comment: Yeah, that works. But what's wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 10):

A very simple modification (adding `?NumericQ`) achieves the result you expected.

```
i = 0;
f[x_?NumericQ] := (i += 1; Tanh[x] Sin[Exp[x]] Exp[-0.55 x^2 Exp[x^2]])
Print[NIntegrate[f[x], {x, -2, 1}]]
Print[i]

(* 0.0901049*)

(*122*)
```

The issue is that `NIntegrate` tries to evaluate `f[x]` symbolically.  In your version, it is called only once and is replaced by `Tanh[x] Sin[Exp[x]] Exp[-0.55 x^2 Exp[x^2]`.  In my version, the `f[x]` is returned unchanged until specific numerical values are given to `x`.

Comment: My +1 for actually explaining the problem in the OP's approach!